# Why won't my javascript recognize strings that have line breaks in them?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, erb

In my Rails program I have a script that gets a string from my database and passes it with erb to a function in javascript. However, when the string gathered from the database has a line break in it (like a newline character from pressing 'enter') I end up in the following situation:

```
<%= puts @comment[:reference] %>
```

prints the string correctly in the console, with the blank lines included.

But,

```
alert('<%= @comment[:reference] %>')
```

does nothing!

I have no issues when the string is contained in one line.

Why is my string being interpreted correctly within the erb tag, but failing to pass correctly to the javascript?

Comment: I'm guessing/hoping that the issue is as simple a miscommunication between the string's encoding in mysql and the encoding required by javascript.

Comment: You should use raw before any result when you do it in Javascript, maybe thats is your solution: alert('<%= raw  @comment[:reference] %>')